# Java equivalent of typeof(SomeClass)

Tags: java, generics

I try to implement a

```
Hashtable<string, -Typeof one Class->
```

in Java. But I don't have an idea of how to get this working. I tried

```
Hashtable<String, AbstractRestCommand.class>
```

but this seems to be wrong.

Btw. I want this to create a new instance of the class per reflection at runtime.

So my question is, how to do this kind of stuff.

Edit:

I have the abstract Class "AbstractRestCommand". Now I would like to create a Hashtable with many commands like this:

```
        Commands.put("PUT",  -PutCommand-);
    Commands.put("DELETE", -DeleteCommand-);
```

where PutCommand and DeleteCommand extends AbstractRestCommand, so that I can create a new instance with

```
String com = "PUT"
AbstractRestCommand command = Commands[com].forName().newInstance();
...
```

Comment: Do you mean `Hashtable<String, AbstractRestCommand>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to create a mapping of a string to a class? This can be done this way:

```
Map<String, Class<?>> map = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
map.put("foo", AbstractRestCommand.class);
```

If you want to restrict the restrict the possible types to a certain interface or common super class you can use a bounded wildcard which would later allow you to use the mapped class objects to create objects of that type:

```
Map<String, Class<? extends AbstractRestCommand>> map =
                    new HashMap<String, Class<? extends AbstractRestCommand>>();
map.put("PUT", PutCommand.class);
map.put("DELETE", DeleteCommand.class);
...
Class<? extends AbstractRestCommand> cmdType = map.get(cmdName);
if(cmdType != null)
{
    AbstractRestCommand command = cmdType.newInstance();
    if(command != null)
        command.execute();
}
```

Comment: If all your commands extends AbstractRestCommand you only need to do a simple: `Hashtable<String, AbstractRestCommand>` All this code is completly redundant

Comment: @yes123: A mapping to a Class object can make sense, i.e. if you want be able to execute multiple instances in parallel. Even if the commands itself are stateless it can still be more convenient to allow the implementations to have temporary state.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant:

```
Hashtable<String, ? extends AbstractRestCommand>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Hashtable<string, Object>
```

Edit:

After reading your edit you can just do:

```
Hashtable<String, AbstractRestCommand>
```

Comment: if it works and it's much easier to understand and doens't shot warnings why don't use?

Comment: It enforces a downcast to do anything on values of the map, this breaks the type safety principle by removing the type checking from that point so it's not nice under any circumstance..

Answer (score 1):

Surely you just need

```
Hashtable<String, AbstractRestCommand>
```